# Is there any way to select-highlight a text in pdf file in react native

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, pdf, react-native

I am new at react native, currently i am using this component to show pdf : https://github.com/cnjon/react-native-pdf-view . This component taking a path and open a pdf, and pdf downloading with "react-native-fs". It seems this component converting pdf to like a image,so i cannot select a text with this component i guess, i am not sure what it is doing.

Briefly i want to select-highlight a text from opened pdf and do some work with this text. Is there any way or other component to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I did not find the solution which suites my requirement.

I have written my own login. Below is the code.

```
    const keywordsMarked = ["test"];
    let node = document.getElementsByClassName("your-class");
            if (node && node[0] && node[0].children[0]) {
                let a = node[0].children[0];
                if (a.children[2])
                    a.children[2].style.display = "none";
                if (a.children[1])
                    for (var i = 0; i < a.children[1].children.length; i++) {
                        console.log(a.children[1].children[i].textContent);
                        if (keywordsMarked.some(val => {
                            return a.children[1].children[i].textContent.indexOf(val) >= 0
                        })) {
                            a.children[1].children[i].style.backgroundColor = 'yellow';
                            a.children[1].children[i].style.color = 'black';
                            a.children[1].children[i].style.height = "12px";
                        }                    
                    }


            }
```